# Latent variables for spatio-temporal Extreme Value in R

Tags: r, hierarchical-bayesian, extreme-value, spatio-temporal

Latent variables models are often used for spatial extremes modeling
see e.g.,  [Davison, Padoan and
Ribatet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.3378.pdf).  A typical application
use block maxima such as annual maxima of temperature, assumed to have
a marginal Generalized Extreme Value (GEV) distribution.

In relation with climate change, one may be interested in
spatio-temporal models involving both a spatial index vector
$\mathbf{s}$ (such as the vector formed with longitude and latitude)
and a time index $t$, along with with a vector
$\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{s},\, t)$ of covariables. In such a model, the GEV
location parameter $\mu$ would be

$$ 
\mu(\mathbf{s},\, t) = \boldsymbol{\beta}_\mu^\top
\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{s}, \, t) + \zeta_\mu(\mathbf{s},\,t) 
$$

where $\boldsymbol{\beta}_\mu$ is a vector of unknown coefficients and
$\zeta_\mu(\mathbf{s}, \, t)$ is a latent Gaussian Process. Similar
formulations could be needed for the GEV scale $\sigma$ and shape
$\xi$.

The CRAN package [**SpatialExtremes**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SpatialExtremes/index.html) covers the spatial case. Also, [**INLA**](https://www.r-inla.org/) covers some special cases and further provides an alternative
based on the *blended GEV* distribution for the case of a constant
positive shape $\xi >0$. Using [**Stan**](https://mc-stan.org/) via **RStan** is an option but there does not
yet seem to exist an **RStan** package devoted to Extreme Value.

So: what R packages can be used for the estimation and the Bayesian
inference for this kind of models?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how this question can be closed as being "off-topic". Searching on "packages" on CV I see many questions that should have been deleted as well. Also this is clearly not a question for SO.

Comment: When you find questions that are not on topic, please flag them.  Their presence *never* justifies posting another off-topic question.

Comment: Well I often do not find these questions off-topic,  which may explain my surprise. I believe that inquiring about the existence of R packages devoted to sensible yet not widespread statistical models is not a question about programming but rather about practical statistical analysis, the first topic in the target list given on CV. To my eyes in the message: "*it focuses on programming, debugging, or performing routine operations, or it asks about obtaining datasets*" nothing applies to my question.

Comment: I am sympathetic to that point of view, but it is contrary to what this site's policies have been for many years.  Moreover, you have a good resource for `R` package searches in CRAN.

Comment: Yes I will use the CRAN search, although details provided by users could have helped. Thank you.